# TouchXML XPath query help

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, xpath, touchxml

I have an xml I am using TouchXML to parse it. Basically, a Lookup looks like this:

```
                    <Lookup>
                    <LookupID>201150103538705</LookupID>
                    <LookupName  />
                    <LookupType>Category</LookupType>
                    <VendorID>10</VendorID>
                    </Lookup>
```

When I do this, it returns all Lookup in the document:

```
NSArray *lookups = [[xmlDoc rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"//TestA:Lookup"
                                    namespaceMappings:mappings 
                                                error:nil];
```

What I want to do is get all lookups whos LookupType is equal to Composition (string compare). So this is what's I have tried and it returns null:

```
NSArray *lookups = [[xmlDoc rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"//TestA:Lookup[LookupType=\"Composition\"]" 
                                    namespaceMappings:mappings 
                                                error:nil];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the XPath `//TestA:Lookup[TestA:LookupType='Composition']` do what you want? If the parent element is in a namespace then its child too so I think you need a prefix on both elements in your path.

Comment: Hey that worked! thanks. One last question: if i want to get LookupName rather than Lookup, how would I do it? Currently I tried this but it doesn't work: @"//TestA:Lookup[TestA:LookupType='Composition']/LookupName"

Comment: Well if the elements are in a namespace then in your XPath expression you need to use a prefix to qualify element names so try `"//TestA:Lookup[TestA:LookupType='Composition']/TestA:LookupName`.